# Which software is available to connect to and manage cell phones?

Tags: software-recommendation, phone

Is there any application that can connect to my Nokia 2700c phone and check my messages, applications, files, etc?

Is there some application available in Ubuntu like the Nokia PC Suite, for Windows?

I saw some applications like `kmobiletools` in software center but nothing is working.

Comment: Check this link http://tuxmobil.org/phones_linux_nokia_other.html

Answer (score 4):

**[Wammu](http://wammu.eu/)** ([Click To install](http://apt.marcoceppi.com/p/wammu))

> It works with any phone that Gammu supports, including many models from Nokia, Siemens, and Alcatel. It has complete support (read, edit, delete, copy) for contacts, todo, and calendar. It can read, save, and send SMS. It includes an SMS composer for multi-part SMS messages, and it can display SMS messages that include pictures. Currently, only text and predefined bitmaps or sounds can be edited in the SMS composer. It can export messages to an IMAP4 server (or other email storage).

It cannot browse the files on a phone.For that you can use gMobileMedia.

[**gMobileMedia**](http://gmobilebrowser.sourceforge.net/) ([Click To Install](http://apt.marcoceppi.com/p/gmobilemedia))

> A short description this application let's you easily upload and download images, ringtones, photos and applications to your mobile phone, all that you need is a data cable or any other connection method supported by gammu.
>
> This application has been targeted mainly for Nokia cell phones (I only have those to test), but theoretically it can handle all the phones that gammu has support for.  This is also because I never could found an easy to use alternative in Linux for Nokia's PC Suite.

Comment: i have already tried gMobileMedia. but could not connect.I have tried with data cable.how to set the settings in it?

Comment: please help me to connect my phone in this.

Comment: @Sreejith you can connect with usb cable and then try different ports in the prefrences(file -> Prefrences).

Comment: there is lot of options cant understand anything.My phone is nokia 2700c (java phone).connection by data cable to usb.

Comment: @Sreejith you should start a new question for "how to configure gmobilemedia for your phone?"